# Which Drupal functions can be called in hook_requirements('install')?

Tags: hooks

Generally, implementations of [hook_requirements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7) don't use any Drupal function, when they are invoked during installation. [node_requirements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_requirements/7) uses some Drupal functions for whatever phase it is invoked.

```
  $requirements = array();
  // Ensure translations don't break at install time
  $t = get_t();
  // Only show rebuild button if there are either 0, or 2 or more, rows
  // in the {node_access} table, or if there are modules that
  // implement hook_node_grants().
  $grant_count = db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {node_access}')->fetchField();
  if ($grant_count != 1 || count(module_implements('node_grants')) > 0) {
    $value = format_plural($grant_count, 'One permission in use', '@count permissions in use', array('@count' => $grant_count));
  }
  else {
    $value = $t('Disabled');
  }
```

Which Drupal functions can be called in `hook_requirements('install')`?

Comment: Isn't that going to be an extremely long list? It might be better to ask which functions _can't_ be called without checking the phase

Comment: The answer doesn't necessarily need to list each single function; it could just be "You can call any function defined in bootstrap.inc." I don't need a complete list, which would be obsolete as soon as Drupal defines new functions, or moves a function from a file to another.

Comment: Gotcha. Interesting question by the way I'm hoping this gets answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made severals tests and I found that depending on modules that you've installed or other things the list of available functions is quite different.

So, IMHO the best way to see which functions you can access at that moment its to list them with the PHP function [get_defined_functions](http://ch2.php.net/get_defined_functions). Below it's the small code that I used to list all the functions you can use.

```
<?php
if ($phase == 'install') {
  $funcs = get_defined_functions();
  file_put_contents('./functions.txt', var_export($funcs['user'], 1));
}
```

Comment: When I said _Drupal functions_, I was more interested on the functions Drupal defines in its includes/*.inc files; then I thought that some Drupal core modules could also be available too. I was not considering the difference between Drupal bootstrapped from Drush and Drupal bootstrapped because an administrative page being required, or any third-party modules. Probably I should at least consider Drupal being bootstrapped from Drush.